# Extracting Content when Multiple Children with Same Name (Google Scripts JS)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, parent-child

I'm not sure how to extract content when there are multiple optional children with the same name.

1. Individuals can have multiple children with the same name. e.g.
   `user_defined_text_field` below.
2. Some individuals may not have any children.

Hopefully the example below provides the relevant context.

**FORM OF DATA**

(From an API from a service)

```
<api>
 <response>
      <service>api_search</service>
      <individuals count="1">
          <individual id="1">
                    <first_name>James</first_name>
                    <last_name>Jones</last_name>
                    <email>jjones@gmail.com</email>
                    <gender>M</gender>
                    <user_defined_text_fields>
                         <user_defined_text_field>
                              <name>udf_text_1</name>
                              <label>Fav Color</label>
                              <text>Blue</text> // ****** I WANT THIS ******
                              <admin_only>false</admin_only>
                         </user_defined_text_field>
                         <user_defined_text_field>
                              <name>udf_text_3</name>
                              <label>Area</label>
                              <text>Urban</text>
                              <admin_only>false</admin_only>
                         </user_defined_text_field>
                    </user_defined_text_fields>
          </individual>               
      </individuals>
 </response>
```

**CURRENT PORTION OF CODE TO EXTRACT RELEVANT DATA**

(Inside Google Script. Everything is working perfect -- I only need help with the line I have commented below.)

```
// ...

const entries = fetch.getRootElement().getChild('response').getChild('individuals').getChildren();
const list = new Array();

for (let i in entries) { 

  const first_name = entries[i].getChildText('first_name');
  const last_name = entries[i].getChildText('last_name');
  const email = entries[i].getChildText('email');
  const gender = entries[i].getChildText('gender');


  const fav_color = ???  // ****** NEED HELP HERE ******


  list.push([first_name, last_name, email, gender]);
};


// ...
```

Comment: From `Everything is working perfect`, when I saw your XML data, if `fetch` is ` const fetch = XmlService.parse(xmlData)`, I thought that `fetch.getRootElement().getChild('response')` is `null`. So I cannot understand your situation. I apologize for this. So, I'm worried that even when I proposed the modification point, that might not be the direct solution to your issue. So, can I ask you about the detailed information for correctly replicating `Everything is working perfect` using your showing XML data? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description

Since `user_defined_text_fields` contains an array of `user_defined_text_field`, you have to loop through the array of children to get to the one that has the color.

Script

```
for (let i in entries) { 

  var first_name = entries[i].getChildText('first_name');
  var last_name = entries[i].getChildText('last_name');
  var email = entries[i].getChildText('email');
  var gender = entries[i].getChildText('gender');
  var fields = entries[i].getChild("user_defined_text_fields");
  var children = fields.getChildren("user_defined_text_field");
  if( children ) {
    for( var j=0; j<children.length; j++ ) {
      if( children[j].getChildText("label") === "Fav Color" ) {
        var fav_color = children[j].getChildText("text");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getChildren(String)